# WPF, two-way binding to a hash table doesn't update the source object

Tags: wpf, data-binding, hashtable, two-way-binding

I am wondering if anyone can help, I am able to bind to a hash table and display values correctly, yet the two-way binding I have specified doesn't update the object when I make changes.

```
   <DataTemplate x:Key="ResponseItemTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <TextBox Width="200" Text="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

I don't know if it's anything to do with it being in a DataTemplate?

Comment: This question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190440/wpf-two-way-binding-to-a-hash-table/1191002#1191002

Answer (score 1):

Enumeration over a `Hashtable` yields a sequence of `DictionaryEntry` objects, but `DictionaryEntry` is a struct, not a class... so you actually get a copy of the `DictionaryEntry`, so when its value is modified, it doesn't actually modify the entry in the `Hashtable`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use {Binding Path=Value.YOURPROPERTYYOUWANTTOMODIFY ....
currently you are binding directly to the object which is in the value property.